# Incidence and prevalence of tendinopathies

Tags: data-request, medical

I am looking for a data set that contains the incidence and prevalence of tendinopathies,  with as many following fields as possible:

- Year
- geolocation
- location of the tendinopathy (rotator cuff, the Achilles tendon, the patellar ligament, the adductors of the hip, the triceps, the flexors and extensors of the elbow, the plantar fascia, …)
- patient demographics
- patient's main activity